# Opening a pdf file on Android doesn't work

Tags: c#, android, pdf, path, unity-game-engine

I tried

```
public void OpenPDF(string filename)
{
    TextAsset pdfTemp = Resources.Load ("pdf/" + filename, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename + ".pdf", pdfTemp.bytes);
    Application.OpenURL(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename + ".pdf");
}
```

and also did

```
void OnClick(){
    string path;
             //set the correct path to the rules files
    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android) {
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, Tag.rulesFilename);
        WWW www = new WWW(path);
        Application.OpenURL(www.url); //intent launches but nothing happens
    }
    else {
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, Tag.rulesFilename); 
        Application.OpenURL(path);
    }
}
```

and already did

```
public void OpenPDF(string filename)
{
string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, filename + ".pdf");

    TextAsset pdfTemp = Resources.Load(filename, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;

    File.WriteAllBytes(path, pdfTemp.bytes);

    Application.OpenURL(path);
}
```

My pdf file, "voca.pdf" doesn't show up ever.
Tried in Resources folder, Assets folder, StreamingAssets
Those codes are from http://answers.unity3d.com/
But toast messages on android say only "Cannot open the file"

How could you figure out this?
I would be thankful if done.